# NPN transistors as a switch with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, npn

I'm trying to use 2 NPN transistors as a switch as shown in image-1.

When I connect pins 4 and 5 of the Arduino to the base of each transistor it works fine, but when I try connecting pin 5 to the base of both transistors it does not work (image-2.)

Why is this happening?

The code of the Arduino is just to set both pins on high:

```
void setup()
{
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
   digitalWrite(5 , HIGH);
   digitalWrite(4 , HIGH);
}
```

[image: Image-1]
[image: Image-2]

Comment: Please draw an actual schematic, not this mess.

Comment: Can you provide a real schematic, please? These sorts of cartoon diagrams are not as helpful as a proper schematic. You should also tell us the values or all resistors, the part number of the transistor, and give us a link to the datasheet for the transistor. By the way, did you connect ground on your transistor circuit to the Arduino's ground?

Comment: What value of base resistors are you using, and is one shared, or does each transistor have its own?

Comment: is it BCE on N? from L to R?  if one E is to 0V and the other to V+ which will not work

Comment: Are you a member of a robotics team? Il

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to start by drawing a circuit diagram from your wiring diagram.  Circuit diagrams are easier to understand and discuss.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feFwVJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With a properly drawn circuit diagram, it becomes obvious that you have some serious problems.

1. You have the 9V battery wired backwards.
2. D4, D7, and D3 are connected such that current can only flow from the collector to the emitter of your transistors - that is backwards from the normal use of an NPN transistor.
3. You have no resistors to limit current through the base of the transistors.
4. You have no resistor to limit current through the LED.
5. You have diodes all over the place in an attempt to force the current to go where you want it to go.

I expect it works with D4 and D5 because it takes both of them together to provide enough current to the transistor bases to make the transistors operate in reverse.

Besides all of that, there is no need to switch the high and low side of the LED.

The normal way to switch an LED from a microprocessor uses only one digital output and one transistor.

It looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR9EoG.png)</sup>

One transistor, two resistors, one LED.  Easy to understand.

Since you have an Arduino in hand, you can eliminate the 9V battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4PeUB.png)</sup>

Just use the 5V pin from the Arduino.  Tada, no battery needed.

---

NPN transistors can be used in reverse, they just don't work as well as when used normally.

You could connect one as in this diagram, and expect the LED to light in response to D4:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsR9n7.png)</sup>

Notice that the base resistor (R2) is much smaller in this case.  The transistor will work backwards, it just doesn't work well.  The current amplification in reverse is much lower than when used normally - more current has to flow through the base to get enough current through the collector-emitter path to make the LED light up.

Your original circuit in fact has the transistors operating backwards like this circuit.

---

A further note:

Your code doesn't change the output values of D4 or D5 in the loop.  It continually sets them to the same value.  You could achieve the same effect by moving the "digitalWrite" commands to the "setup" method, leaving the "loop" method empty.

Comment: Oh, no wonder I couldn't make any sense of that wiring diagram!

Comment: @Hearth:  It took me a couple of attempts to realize what (all) was wrong with the wiring diagram.

Comment: Thanks .. I only started doing these circuits two days ago so I dont really know much about this stuff .. I was trying to create a circuit to control the direction of electric flow using arduino .. to control a DC motor

Comment: @AbdoWise:  If you are trying to make a motor turn in one direction, then it is (almost) as easy as turning on the LED.  If you want to make the motor run forwards and backwards under control of your Arduino, then it becomes more complicated.  You'll need to look into using an ["H-bridge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-bridge) to make the motor run in either direction.

Comment: @JRE thanks for the advice

Comment: @JRE is there any good website to learn how to build electric circuits .. although I dont understand half of what you said I started to like this stuff :)